# CSS issue styling button

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to style a button with CSS. Here is the HTML code for the button:

```
<button class='custombtn' name="doLogin" type="submit" id="doLogin3" value="Login">Login</button>
```

Here is the CSS code.

```
.custombtn {
    width:163px;
    height:43px;
    background-image:url('images/normal.png');
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
}
.custombtn:hover {
    background-image:url('images/hover.png');
}
.custombtn:active {
    background-image:url('images/click.png');
}
```

I thought everything was fine & dandy, until I viewed the results. 
Instead of something like this with text on it:

[image]

It looks like this:

[image]

I've been reading fixes for these online for around an hour and a half, however none of them have worked. I know it's possible to style it to look like this, I just need to find a way.

**normal.png**

[image]

**hover.png**

[image]

**click.png**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly set `border:none; background-color:transparent;` on `.custombtn`.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to Style the button upon click?

Comment: `:hover` will apply to the button anytime the mouse cursor is over it. `:active` will apply to the button as long as the mouse button is held down on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the border to none. That should definitely solve the problem and make sure there is no white space in the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the button's background and borders are the cause of your headache.

Try something like this:

```
.custombtn {
    margin: 10px;
    width:163px;
    height:43px;
    background-image:url('images/normal.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
.custombtn:hover {
    background-image:url('images/hover.png');
}
.custombtn:active {
    background-image:url('images/click.png');
}​
```

Comment: `none` is not a valid CSS color value. You want `transparent` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color_value